# jQuery Mobile Panel - Linking within Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been looking around for a while to find this answer but I am having no luck.

Within my jQuery mobile panel I am trying to link to a section of the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<!--- PANEL MENU --->
<div data-role="panel" id="firstpanel">
<a href="#test">test</a></li>
</div>

<!--- CONTENT -->
<div class="content" data-role="content">
<a name="test"></a>
</div>
```

This is not working within the panel code.  Any ideas why this might not work? I tried using an absolute link (http://www.google.com) and it worked fine. I am just having trouble with linking to a section within the page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my original answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery mobile you can use the `$.mobile.silentScroll()` (https://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/) method to move to an element within the page. So for your example you could handle the click event of the link in the panel, read the href of the link to get the id of the destination element. get the top offset of that element and finally scroll to the element:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="firstpanel">
    <ul id="navigation" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#test" class="scrollTo">Show #test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $(".scrollTo").on("click", function(){
        var elem = $(this).prop("href");
        elem = elem.substr(elem.lastIndexOf("#"));
        //scroll to elem
        var top = $(elem).offset().top;
        $.mobile.silentScroll( top );
        return false;
    });
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/47Y5x/)**

**NOTE:** In the demo, the link scrolls you to the name Tristan.